# Laravel routing working on local server but not on cpanel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on laravel 5.5.33. I have created few pages like **index.blade.php**, **about.blade.php** etc. in view folder.

The routing for both the pages are working perfectly on local machine.
Then I migrated the project folder to my shared hosting.
The routing for the page **index.blade.php** is working perfectly but the same function is not working for any other file e.g **about.blade.php**.

web.php

```
// This function is working for index file
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

// This function is not working for about file
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view ('about');
});
```

header.blade.php

```
<ul>
<li class="mega-menu"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="mega-menu"><a href="about">About Us</a></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: does anything working on cpanel ?

Comment: yes the landing page is working i.e index.blade.php

Comment: do one more thing dd before return view about and check weather you are enter in that route or not

Answer (score 5):

I Think You Have Just Moved You .htaccess file from the public or public_html folder.

You have to copy it not cut/move it.

Just paste a copy of .htaccess file in public or public_html folder and it's done.

Answer (score 0):

just add this code on .htacces

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And save the .htacces file in public_html

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the path in the [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-url) helper

`<li class="mega-menu"><a href="{{url('/about')}}">About Us</a></li>`

I'd also double check you have `mod_rewrite` switched on if apache (or whatever is the NGINX/{insert server here} equivalent)

---

or even better add a name to your routes and then call that on the blade template:

```
// This function is working for index file
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
})->name('index');

// This function is not working for about file
Route::get('about', function () {
    return view ('about');
})->name('about');
```

and

```
<li class="mega-menu"><a href="{{route('about')}}">About Us</a></li>
```

You can get your route names from `php artisan route:list` and read about the helper [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route).

Comment: how to check mod_rewrite is switched on or not?

Comment: Does *http://yoururl.com/index.php/about* do anything? And do you have a standard Laravel **.htaccess**? Using a terminal, you would (ubuntu/debian) do `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

Route defined:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('about', 'HomeController@about');
```

controller code:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('homes.index'); // homes is folder name and index is index.blade.php , below follow image .
}


public function about()
{
    return view('about.about');
}
```

Html Code:

```
<ul>
<li class="mega-menu"><a href="{{('/')}}">Home</a></li>
<li class="mega-menu"><a href="{{ url('about')}}">About Us</a></li>
<ul>
```

[image]